# How to access Bash on Ubuntu through Git Bash?

Tags: windows, bash, git, powershell, ubuntu

I use git bash on Hyper as my main terminal. I have recently installed Ubuntu on Bash with Windows Subsystem. When I type `bash` on Windows Command Line or Powershell, it opens Ubuntu on Bash as expected. But as switched over to Git Bash and type `bash` again it does nothing.

How to access Bash on Ubuntu through Git Bash?

**Edit:** I checked the PATH from both terminals as requested, they are exactly the same. Therefore it is not a PATH thing.

Comment: could you `echo $env:Path` in powershell and `echo $PATH` in Git Bash? I suspect that git bash either doesn't include the windows subsystem bash or overrules it with itself

Comment: It looks exactly the same. I don't know if you want the full output but they use same path.

Comment: okay, not a path thing, if they are the same, no need to share them, maybe edit your question to mention that path is the same in each

Comment: Git bash and Ubuntu on Bash uses same alias `bash`. Could it to be related to that?

Comment: I'm confused.  Why use `git bash` at all, when you could just install actual `git` on `bash` on `ubuntu`?

Comment: Because I don't want to use Ubuntu on Bash as main terminal. I just want to be able to switch between them.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/